# pointPolygonTest in OpenCV confuses inside and outside of the contour

Tags: opencv, contour

I need to track a point and see if it is inside a contour or not. I find the contours using findContour function of OpenCV and it gives me 3 contours, so I merge them using numpy concatenate function and then use the pointPolygonTest to determine if a point is inside or outside it. but there is this region that is obviously inside the contour and I am getting a negative distance when the point is inside it.

first wanted to know if it is okay to merge contours. if not then how should I know if the point is inside or outside?

[image]

here is the original image:
[image]

Comment: Can you post original image?

Comment: Without any merging, simply run 3 separate tests -- first check if the point is in the big outer contour. If it is, then check that it's *not* inside either of the two inner contours. If all tests are true, then it lies inside the green area.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks I just did that